# apache virtual host question

Tags: apache, virtualhost

After i 've set a virtual host in httpd.conf,
why i still have to set the virtual host in domain registration organization?

I'clarify

for example , i've set phpmyadmin.mydomain.com as virtual host in httpd conf file, next, i've to go to http://www.dyndns.com/ to add phpmyadmin.mydomain.com as A record, so phpmyadmin.mydomain.com will be accessible.

Comment: Do you mean the following? YOU have a webserver which is reachable globally and have properly setup the vHost for your registered domain on this server. But at your registry you have to re-configure that? Normally you set the names of the `nameserver` for that domain and the thing is done. The nameserver then points the visitor of your website to your webserver IP where (hopefully) the vHost is configured! ;-)

Comment: Not sure how to answer you ... how we know what domain name you have registered ? Give us some clues ...

Comment: Please clarify this question, it's impossible to answer in its current form

Answer (score 1):

> After i 've set a virtual host in httpd.conf,
>
> why i still have to set the virtual host in domain registration organization?

These are two separate tasks because they touch entirely different areas.

DNS records tell *the world* that domain A is now reachable on IP address B (Imperfect real world analogy: an entry in the phone book)

The `VirtualHost` directive  tells *the server software running on the server* how to deal with incoming requests to that domain. (Imperfect real world analogy: Your name on the doorbell of a large house, and on your mail box in the hallway of the house.)

Comment: but i use some services of hosting company to add the subdomain, it don't need me to do extra thing to get the subdomain work

Comment: @friends what is your question then? I don't understand.